# How do I convert multiple time formats in the same column to then convert it as a standard time format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column where the timestamp data is in two different formats. MM:SS and HH:MM:SS I'm trying to convert it to a standard format so I can do calculations on it. however `pd.to_datetime()` does not recognize this since they are not in a consistent format.

Example:

```
'59:14', '59:16', '59:20', '59:21', '59:24', '59:24', '59:27',
'59:26', '59:29', '59:31', '59:37', '59:39', '59:40', '59:41',
'59:43', '59:44', '59:46', '59:49', '59:51', '59:52', '59:53',
'59:54', '59:55', '59:57', '1:00:02', '1:00:05', '1:00:09',
'1:00:10', '1:00:14', '1:00:17', '1:00:20', '1:00:21', '1:00:22',
'1:00:24', '1:00:29', '1:00:31', '1:00:35', '1:00:37', '1:00:36',
'1:00:41', '1:00:44', '1:00:45', '1:00:50', '1:00:52', '1:00:57',
'1:01:10', '1:01:12', '1:01:14', '1:01:16', '1:01:19', '1:01:21'
```

Comment: pd.to_timedelta()?

Comment: I get "ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format" because the the top portion of the data does not have leading 0's in place for the hour. It has no hour. So essentially there are two different data types.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your column to be converted is *Time*.

To convert it to *timedelta*, apply a "specialized" conversion function,
something like:

```
df.Time.apply(lambda txt: pd.to_timedelta('0:' + txt if len(txt) < 6 else txt))
```

Instead of *to_timedelta* you may also apply *to_datetime*, but the downside
is that the date part is taken from the current day.

"Vanilla" application of *pd.to_timedelta* (as advised in one of comments)
will fail with exception `ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format`.

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess your times before giving it to pd.to_datetime.

For example:

```
times = ['59:14', '59:16', '59:20', '59:21', '59:24', '59:24', '59:27',
'59:26', '59:29', '59:31', '59:37', '59:39', '59:40', '59:41',
'59:43', '59:44', '59:46', '59:49', '59:51', '59:52', '59:53',
'59:54', '59:55', '59:57', '1:00:02', '1:00:05', '1:00:09',
'1:00:10', '1:00:14', '1:00:17', '1:00:20', '1:00:21', '1:00:22',
'1:00:24', '1:00:29', '1:00:31', '1:00:35', '1:00:37', '1:00:36',
'1:00:41', '1:00:44', '1:00:45', '1:00:50', '1:00:52', '1:00:57',
'1:01:10', '1:01:12', '1:01:14', '1:01:16', '1:01:19', '1:01:21']

clean_times = list(map(lambda elt: '00:' + elt if elt.count(':') == 1 else elt, times))
pandas_times = pd.to_datetime(clean_times)
```

Will give you the following output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-25 00:59:14', '2019-11-25 00:59:16',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:20', '2019-11-25 00:59:21',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:24', '2019-11-25 00:59:24',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:27', '2019-11-25 00:59:26',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:29', '2019-11-25 00:59:31',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:37', '2019-11-25 00:59:39',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:40', '2019-11-25 00:59:41',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:43', '2019-11-25 00:59:44',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:46', '2019-11-25 00:59:49',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:51', '2019-11-25 00:59:52',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:53', '2019-11-25 00:59:54',
               '2019-11-25 00:59:55', '2019-11-25 00:59:57',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:02', '2019-11-25 01:00:05',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:09', '2019-11-25 01:00:10',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:14', '2019-11-25 01:00:17',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:20', '2019-11-25 01:00:21',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:22', '2019-11-25 01:00:24',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:29', '2019-11-25 01:00:31',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:35', '2019-11-25 01:00:37',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:36', '2019-11-25 01:00:41',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:44', '2019-11-25 01:00:45',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:50', '2019-11-25 01:00:52',
               '2019-11-25 01:00:57', '2019-11-25 01:01:10',
               '2019-11-25 01:01:12', '2019-11-25 01:01:14',
               '2019-11-25 01:01:16', '2019-11-25 01:01:19',
               '2019-11-25 01:01:21'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to make the column look as you expected then apply pd.to_datetime()

See Possible Solution Below

```
# Append 00: to time column if count of ':' is 1
#Define a function that performs row by row operations
def clean_time_col(the_time_col):
    if str(the_time_col).count(':')==1:
        the_time_col='00:'+the_time_col 
    return time_col

#Use Apply to perform row operations on time_col
df['new_time_col'] = df['time_col'].apply(def_clean_time_col)
```

Code Untested